# Python - Using einsum as a kron product and average

Tags: python, numpy, loops, average

I am generating a large set of M NxN matrices, where both M and N is large, so I am trying to look for an efficient way to do some calculations.
The NxN matrix, let's call it A, is generated by the kron product of two smaller matrices, i.e.

```
for n_i,n in enumerate(t_list):
    for m in range(M):
        A[:,:,n_i,m]=np.kron(a_1[:,:,n_i,m],a_2[:,:,n_i,m])
```

where a_1 and a_2 are two square matrices. Notice how I have a loop over some array (t_list) and over the set of M. I would like to avoid this sort of loop by being able to take the kron product directly. Unfortunately, it is not possible to use np.kron(a,b,axis).

Not only that, the issue is that I actually do not care about this matrix A, because I only can about the average of its elements such

```
for n_i,n in enumerate(t_list):
    A_avg[:,:,n_i]=np.mean(A[:,:,n_i,:],axis=2)
```

So, I am only generating A to later on average over its element to get A_avg. Because M is large, A is a large matrix which I have to store, something I should avoid.

I have the feeling I could avoid all these loops by using np.einsum. Unfortunately, I have not been able to do it. Could somebody guide me?

Comment: I haven't worked with `kron` recently, but I believe it contains all the values of an outer product, only arranged differently.  So you could use `einsum` to calculate the outer.  Then identify where the desired blocks are.  That may require some reshaping (maybe transpose as well, though you can do that in `einsum` as well).  `einsum` can sum, or with an appropriate `weights`  array, do a mean.  Providing a [mcve] might make this a more attractive question to work those details.

Comment: For (2,2) arrays, `np.einsum('ij,kl->ikjl',y,x).reshape(4,4)` is the same as `kron(y,x)`

Comment: `np.kron(y,x).sum(axis=1)`, `np.einsum('ij,kl->ijkl',y,x).sum((1,3))` produce the same numbers (for any 2d `y` and `x`).

Comment: @hpaulj thank you for those answers! They helped, but I am still struggling. My problem is that the x and y matrices have 4 indices, x[i,j,k,l], y[i,j,k,l] and I need to take the kron between the two firsts, z[i,j,k,l]=kron(x[:,:,k,l], y[:,:,k,l]), and then take the average of the last one mean(z[i,j,k,:]). Everything while keeping  'k' free, if possible without calling a loop. I do not know how to write it in a compact and efficient way.

Comment: @hpaulj or in other words, given x[i,j,k,l], y[i,j,k,l], I would like to have something like kron(x[:,:,:,:], y[:,:,:,:])_{i,j}.sum{l}, where the order matters: first the kron product, then the sum

Comment: I just illustrated the 2d case - expanding to 4, and then back to 2.  You may have to add some more indices to handle 4d inputs - 4 to 8 and back?  I experimented with (2,2) and (3,3) arrays; you can do the same with larger.

Comment: @hpaulj I managed to do it! I actually got a 5x speed-up with respect to my original method. Thank you!